# Do we need multiple if constexpr (...) in case of multiple if statements?

Tags: c++, if-statement, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

I know in case of `if constexpr(bool_test)` compiler will throw away `else` statement and it's body content or vice versa depending on if expression evaluates to true or false.

However if we have mutiple `if` `else if` do we need to specify `constexpr` for each of `if` statement or is one enough?

for example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class test { };

template <typename T>
struct is_test1 : public std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_test2 : public std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_test3 : public std::false_type { };

template<>
struct is_test3<test> : public std::true_type { };

int main()
{
    if constexpr(is_test1<test>::value)
    {

    }
    else if constexpr(is_test2<test>::value)
    {

    }
    else if constexpr(is_test3<test>::value)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

what happens if we declare `if constexpr` only for first `if` how does compiler handle other `if`'s are they compile time expressions that is does compiler throw away the rest even if no `constexpr` is specified?

For example we could write this instead, but does compiler throw away all except one which evaluates to true:

```
int main()
{
    if constexpr (is_test1<test>::value)
    {

    }
    else if (is_test2<test>::value)
    {

    }
    else if (is_test3<test>::value)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: for each.......

Comment: @max66 isn't `std::for_each` used for containers only? anyway I have only two `else if`'s in my case.

Comment: "for each" was the response to your question "do we need to specify constexpr for each of if statement or is one enough?" - no "`std::for_each`" involved.

Comment: ah ok, I was attempting to type less, but instead we need to do it for each :)